# SharePoint online ExecuteQuery command giving exception

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, powershell-script

I am writing a powershell script to copy the sharepoint online list items from one sharepoint online list to another while that list consist of 77 fields. I am getting below error. While the same copy code works for list having lesser fields. Do we face problems when we have more number of fields in sharepoint online powershell. There is no attachment or document in list.

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The request message is too big. The server does not allow
messages larger than 2097152 bytes."

Comment: this is a known issue as a result of a soft-limit which can be increased on-prem but not sure how you can overcome it for online. this might provide some additional insight: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ca09905-26b2-4672-b204-7746bac5942e/the-request-message-is-too-big-the-server-does-not-allow-messages-larger-than-2097152-bytes?forum=Office365forDevelopers

Answer (score 0):

It is by default that the maximum file size uploaded is 2 MB if you use content property on the FileCreationInformation class.

You could read this for more: [Upload large files sample SharePoint Add-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint)

Besides, you could refer to this article to upload large files:[Large file upload in SharePoint Online with CSOM PowerShell](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/large-file-upload-in-sharepoint-online-with-csom-powershell/)

Comment: But I am not uploading any file here